# DevExpress XtraReport HtmlItemCreated event not raised

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I'm using DevExpress 2012 Vol 2.4 ASP.NET WebForms controls. I've created a new object of `XtraReport` class and subscribed to its `HtmlItemCreated` event. When I'm calling the `ExportToHtml` method of the `XtraReport` object the event is not getting raised.

I've not posted the markup but there is just a button. When I click the button the event is not triggered. I've put a breakpoint and tested that.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    XtraReport rep = null;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rep = new XtraReport();
        rep.CreateDocument();

        rep.HtmlItemCreated += rep_HtmlItemCreated;

        PageHeaderBand h = new PageHeaderBand();

        XRLabel l = new XRLabel();
        l.Text = "asdasd";

        h.Controls.Add(l);

        rep.Bands.Add(h);
    }

    protected void rep_HtmlItemCreated(object sender, HtmlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ScriptContainer != null)
        {
            string x = "asdasd";
        }
    }

    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sPDFFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "Test.html";
        HtmlExportOptions objPDFExpOpt = rep.ExportOptions.Html;
        objPDFExpOpt.EmbedImagesInHTML = true;
        objPDFExpOpt.ExportMode = HtmlExportMode.DifferentFiles;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty("Test"))
            objPDFExpOpt.Title = "Test";
        rep.ExportToHtml(sPDFFilePath, objPDFExpOpt);
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you doing this.. Put relevant code that support your efforts.. Your statement does not clear everything that you doing in your code..

Comment: @NiranjanKala I've added some code for your reference.

Comment: which component you want to customize.. this event will not work with report, but can be handled on control which are added to the report. e.g. XRLabel that you have added to report controls.\

Comment: @NiranjanKala Actually I wanted to inject a `window.print();` in the html document, so that after the document has been loaded the print window appears.